# Plot Line for Price and Dot for Volume in Twin Axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have my code like:

```
df.plot('Time', ['Price', 'Volume'], secondary_y='Volume', ax=axes[0])
```

By default both are plotted as line. I want the Volume in Second axis to be plotted as Dot(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of line styles to the `style` keyword:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Time' : np.arange(10),
    'Price' : np.random.rand(10)*10,
    'Volume' : np.linspace(1,10,10)**2,
})


df.plot(
    'Time', ['Price', 'Volume'], secondary_y='Volume',
    style = ['-','*'],
    )

plt.show()
```

gives the following plot:

[image: result of above code]